# Simplifying the creation and return of SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently use this code to create and return a `SelectList`:

```
SelectListItem resultError = new SelectListItem() { Text = "An Error Has Occured!", Value = "N/A" };
List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>
{
      resultError
};
return jsSerializer.Serialize(new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text", null).Select(a => new { value = a.Value, text = a.Text }).ToList());
```

Overall it just seems a bit redundant, especially the last linq statement.

```
.Select(a => new { value = a.Value, text = a.Text }).ToList());
```

How can this be simplified?

Comment: Can you add the SelectList class?

Comment: @Orwel sorry not sure what you mean by that! Note: this is what is inside the catch block, so its just returning one item in this case.

Comment: My bad, SelectList is a MVC class.

Comment: @Orwel I am using MVC in this project

Comment: It seems to be a way to create json with lowercase field names.  Just serializing `SelectList` would give "Text":"An Error Has Occured!", "Value":"N/A".  So, it's not great, but not unreasonable, especially as this is an exception condition, so it's not the 'happy path' where performance might be more critical.

Comment: SellectListItem have more properties.

Comment: Not only is the `.Select(.)` redundant, so is the `new SelectList(...)` which just creates another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one. All that is needed is one line of code - `return jsSerializer.Serialize(new { value = "N/A", text = Text = "An Error Has Occured!" });`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var response = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem {
                Text = "An Error has Occured!",
                Value = "N/A"
            }
        };

        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```